# Unable to connect gcloud sql instance

Tags: google-cloud-sql, gcloud

I have create a **cloud sql** instance as shown below -

[image: Cloud SQL instance settings.]

I have also allowed all network (0.0.0.0/0) under authorised network. But when I try to connect it using `gcloud sql connect <ip address> -u <username>` I get this error -

`ERROR: (gcloud.sql.connect) HTTPError 400: Invalid request: instance name (34.69.175.233).`

When I run the same command like this `gcloud sql connect <ip address> -u <username> --log-http` for the log I get this -

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid request: instance name (34.69.175.233).",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid request: instance name (34.69.175.233).",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am not able to identify what exactly is the problem.

Comment: You should be able to connect directly to that instance (on that IP) using a regular MySQL client. `gcloud sql connect ... ` requires the instance name (not IP) and uses the SQL proxy to connect to the instance.

Comment: not able to connect after using instance name via cloud shell

Comment: Aha! Hmmm :-( Let me repro and I'll report back

Comment: I see you're using SQL Server (not MySQL|Postgres) so my previous suggestion to use a MySQL client is incorrect but, I'm reviewing the SQL Server docs.

Comment: I think you cannot use `gcloud sql connect` with SQL Server

Comment: @DazWilkin You were right it doesn't work with the SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, `gcloud sql connect` command is not supported for Cloud SQL Server at this time and you may instead connect via [a local client](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-admin-ip#local), or [the proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-admin-proxy). I have send a feedback to the Cloud SQL Documentation team to clarify that this command is not applicable for Cloud SQL Server in [the gcloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/connect) until the gcloud command gets implemented.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with "cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[connection-name]=tcp:0.0.0.0:[port]"